# Change input shape of MobileNetV3 model in Transfer Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, mobilenet

I'm trying to use grayscale images in a transfer learning attempt. My dataset shape is (160,160,1). I'm following the steps in F. Chollet's tutorial here: https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/

Here's my code:

```
base = k.applications.MobileNetV3Small(
                input_shape=(image_size,image_size,1),
                minimalistic=False,
                include_top=True,
                weights="imagenet")
base.trainable = False

In = k.Input(shape=(image_size,image_size,1))

x = base(In, training=False)

x = k.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

Out = k.layers.Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax')(x)

model = k.Model(In, Out)
```

I get errors related to unmatched input shapes. I tried to include and remove the top layer and play with other settings as well. Here's one of the errors I see:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign to variable Conv/kernel:0 due to variable shape (3, 3, 1, 16) and value shape (16, 3, 3, 3) are incompatible
```

The only thing that works for me with grascale if I remove the imagenet weights altogether from the model as in the below code:

```
### Generate Model
model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV3Small(
                input_shape=(image_size,image_size,1),
                minimalistic=False,
                include_top=True,
                weights=None,
                classes=num_classes,
                pooling=None,
                classifier_activation='softmax')
```

Is there a way to customize the model input shape while keeping the pretrained weights?

Comment: Indeed convolutions are just sliding filters, however number of channels must match (imagenet pretrained has 3 channels), in this case you need your images in RGB format.

Comment: One thing you can try is to stack the same grayscale image thrice to get an RGB image. If you have a data generator and you use some [`flow..`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) method to generate data for training, you can do that by setting `color_mode='rgb'`.

Comment: @akilat90 Yes, I did try that, and it works for execution... but I'm getting much slower training times and not much real benefit from the redundant data